# FilamentPHP select field with relation create new record on parent page

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I have a select field that retrieves all addresses for a relation. I would like to give the user the option to create a address on the page with the select. The documentation of filament says: `createOptionsFrom()` method can be used to achieve this. ([here](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#creating-new-records))

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
Select field [data.relation_address_id] must have a [createOptionUsing()] closure set.
```

This is my form code:

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Forms\Components\Select::make('relation_id')->label('Kies een relatie')->required()
            ->options(Relation::all()->pluck('contact_name', 'id'))
            ->reactive(),
            Forms\Components\Select::make('relation_address_id')->label('Kies een adres')
                ->options(function(callable $get){
                    $relation = Relation::find($get('relation_id'));
                    if(!$relation){
                        return [];
                    }
                    return $relation->addresses()->pluck('name', 'id');
                })->hidden(fn (Closure $get) => $get('relation_id') == null)
                ->createOptionForm([
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')->label('Naam')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('postalcode')->label('Postcode')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('housenumber')->label('Huisnummer')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('street')->label('Straat')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('city')->label('Stad')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\Select::make('country_id')->label('Land')
                            ->options(Country::where('enabled', 1)->pluck('name', 'id'))
                    ]
                ),
        ]);
}
```

This is the relation model:

```
    class Relation extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    public function addresses(){
        return $this->hasMany(RelationAddress::class);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **belongsTo** relation with **createOptionUsing()**

First, update your model to this

```php
class Relation extends Model {
    protected $guarded = [];
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    public function addresses(){
        return $this->belongsTo(RelationAddress::class);
    }
}
```

Second, you have missed **relationship()** method from the form schema

```php
public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Forms\Components\Select::make('relation_id')->label('Kies een relatie')->required()
            ->options(Relation::all()->pluck('contact_name', 'id'))
            ->reactive(),
            Forms\Components\Select::make('relation_address_id')->label('Kies een adres')
                ->options(function(callable $get){
                    $relation = Relation::find($get('relation_id'));
                    if(!$relation){
                        return [];
                    }
                    return $relation->addresses()->pluck('name', 'id');
                })->hidden(fn (Closure $get) => $get('relation_id') == null)
                ->relationship('addresses', 'relation_id')->createOptionForm([
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')->label('Naam')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('postalcode')->label('Postcode')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('housenumber')->label('Huisnummer')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('street')->label('Straat')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('city')->label('Stad')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255),
                        Forms\Components\Select::make('country_id')->label('Land')
                            ->options(Country::where('enabled', 1)->pluck('name', 'id'))
                    ]
                ),
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this does work indeed. The problem is that this lists all of the addresses, I only need the addresses related to the selected relation (the first select). Is this also possible

Comment: @PietHendri, I am also interested in this. Have you found how to do it?